# Django Filtering Query slow on Large row dataset

Tags: django, django-models

- I have been facing a slow performance for my site on performing filtering over large rows from the following data of field. Type of data I'm storing in the field is `RAW HTTP Response Body` in the `body` field which has large content in it, I have 32k objects for below `Project` models.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

- Performing filtering over `body` takes few seconds.

```
>>> Project.objects.filter(body__icontains='x').count() ### 5-6 seconds
20472
```

---

> I use Django paginator for slicing the data for each page.

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> data = Project.objects.filter(body__icontains='x')
>>> p = Paginator(data,10)
>>> p.page(1) ### takes 5-6 seconds here again because this function counts the total number of pages based on data.count()
<Page 1 of 2048>
```

- And then i pass the paginator data to the template which just loop over and shows the body.

```
{% for each_data in data %}
    {{ each_data.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

- For every page of paginator it would take 5-6 seconds wait because paginator function performs the count on the total dataset and return the page range. which is the biggest drawback.

---

> Using Normal Python Slicing :

```
>>> data = Project.objects.filter(body__icontains='x')
>>> for each_data in data[0:10]:  ### 0.1 seconds
        print(each_data.body)
```

- As you can see if we don't hit the database at all and just slice the data and pass it over the template then it would just show the data immediately.

---

- I Believe query becomes slow when `Paginator` function counts the total number of pages for our filtered results for each page.
- I Believe paginator is not suitable for large dataset.

drawbacks of using slicing function are:

- We can't count the total number of results objects returned by the filter.
- can't see the number of pages paginator should have as we are not counting the total dataset.

> Is there any way to tackle this problem for faster results along with pagination?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial if you want to improve pagination: https://medium.com/@hakibenita/optimizing-django-admin-paginator-53c4eb6bfca3

Comment: I have gone through the article & I believe we can do without  pagination itself since we are not counting the total filtered objects returned,  can be done simply with `[offset:limit]` , However, I'm looking for a solution which doesn't compromise the `count on returned objects` or `performance`

Comment: Note that your second example is using the overriden `QuerySet.__getitem__()` implementation, which is not slicing the resultset afterward, but adding "offset" and "limit" clauses to the generated SQL query.

Comment: And while the `count` queries issued by the paginator are indeed part of the overhead, the root issue is the `ilike %x%` condition on a text field. You may want to check your RDBMS manual to find out how to optimize this (if possible at all, of course).

Answer (score 2):

### Why does it happen?

Consider this example:

```
Project.objects.filter(body__icontains='x').count()
```

This will be translated to this query (PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS res
  FROM project
 WHERE UPPER(project.body::text) LIKE UPPER('%x%')
```

If there are a lot of records it will be really slow. How @bruno suggested - try to find a way how to optimize it (it may depend on your RDBMS).

Classical pagination in Django implemented through limit and offset SQL statements. In the result:

COUNT - (Execution time: 10.7s)

OFFSET **X** - DB needs to read X records from the disk after appropriate sorting; Invalid list of elements if a new element has been inserted into a page that has already been requested.

Usually, the count is hashed and when new records added we just make updates. OFFSET is quite hard to optimize(caching?).

### Are there better solutions?

**KEYSET** pagination, the algorithm as follows:

- We remember the identifiers of the first `FIRST_TIMESTAMP` and last
  `LAST_TIMESTAMP` element on the page, for example, this may be the publication date.
- To get the next page we're using construction:

```
WHERE table.date > LAST_TIMESTAMP ORDER_BY date ASC LIMIT <PAGE SIZE>
```

**Advantages:**

- Works much faster on big querysets.
- Correctly processes changes to previous pages when adding new
  elements. There are several [implementations](https://github.com/nitely/django-infinite-scroll-pagination) for Django.

**Disadvantages:**

- Can't switch to the random page, without preloading data, that's why it is
  good for infinite scrolling only.

So, if it is your case, you could significantly speed up the pagination.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to figure out implementing `infinite_scroll_pagination` for this case, can you please provide a simple example suitable for my problem.